# Hide blur overflow from element

Tags: html, css

If I have a very simple image like this:

```
<img src="image.jpg" class="blur">

.blur {
    filter:blur(20px);
    -o-filter:blur(20px);
    -ms-filter:blur(20px);
    -moz-filter:blur(20px);
    -webkit-filter:blur(20px);
}
```

When blurred, the image edges overflow, and blur.

[image: Blur]

What I am trying to do, is blur the image, without the overflow. I have tried wrapping it in a `<div>`, and setting the overflow to hidden:

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="image.png" class="blur">
</div>

.image {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

However, this does not have any effect. Could someone please explain how you do this?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/629yL/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/629yL/1/ Checkout

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put your image just like this, it won't really work. You need to wrap it around in a div  and put it as a background of the div inside the wrapper div.  Then hide the overflow of the parent - this will work.

However, the distortion will still be there and your image will take up considerably more space.

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
<div class="blur"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .box {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin:5px;
}

.blur {
    -webkit-filter: blur(20px);
    margin: -5px 0 0 -5px;
    background: url("http://readwrite.com/files/dogecoin.jpg");
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tMjsJ/306/)**

Answer (score 1):

As of more recently, the accepted answer here is not entirely correct, in that you don't *have* to use a background image. It'll work on a regular `img` as well.

```html
<div style="overflow: initial; display: inline-block;">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300" style="filter: blur(20px)">
</div>

<div style="overflow: hidden; display: inline-block;">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300" style="filter: blur(20px)">
</div>
```

...will give you:
[image: example of blurred images]